# How to input ㅇ with romaji input method?

Tags: vowel

I want to input a single `ㅇ`, with romaji input method ?

I've tried `ng`, but doesn't work, any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer:  https://www.sayjack.com/korean/korean-hangul/type-by-romanization

- For ending consonant, it's `ng`, e.g `yang` -> `양`.
- For other cases, seems no direct input.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if you can enter any Korean character yet or trying it for the first time.

In any case, the first thing to note is that there is no romaji input method.  Because Korean is a phonogram (built on consonants and vowels that map to sounds) like English, you can enter it directly without the help of romaji.

ㅇ is assigned to the "d" key, for instance, in the standard keyboard called "dubeoksik".  So if you're entering 영, you enter ㅇ(d), ㅕ(u), and ㅇ(d).  You'll need to set the language mode to Korean first but this can vary with the OS and possibly with your configuration settings.

Once you get past setting up your environment and familiarizing your fingers to the key mappings, you can enter Korean pretty much as fast as English.  This is one area in which Korean truly excels.  It can even compete with English which is supposed to be the easiest language in this respect.

There are also online keyboards for people who are not quite set up (https://www.sayjack.com/korean/korean-hangul/type-by-dubeolsik/).  On this page you can enter Korean either through the dubeolsik key mapping or by clicking on the keys on the visual keyboard.  You can easily create a Korean sentence using this utility.

Comment: This is not about `romaji`.